# C# multithreading issue

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I have a windows application developed in c# (Visual Studio 2010) which is interacting with a USB-CAN convertor connected to the USB port of the PC. I have implemented a UI on one thread and the transmission and reception logic on a seperate thread. After completion of my task I want to close this thread and return back to the UI thread which is currently hanging!!

I tried to forcefully kill the thread using abort function, but it throws an exception. So how to gracefully end this thread after completion of my task.

I have the following 2 questions:

1. How to gracefully terminate the thread and return to the UI thread?
2. Why is this transmission and reception thread not aborting and hanging the UI thread?

The below piece of code is for your reference:

```
#region recievedthrad
public void ThreadProcReceive()
{
    try
    {
        bool fDoExit = false;

        do
        {
            if (bFlag)
                DeleteAllResources();  // This will free all the driver resources.

            // wait for receiving messages or exiting this thread
            /* Note: After completion of the task, this method needs to return a 0 or 2 value. But still it returns 1 or 258 and never exits the thread. */

            int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(m_RxWaitHandles);
            if (index == 0)
            {
                // exit this thread
                fDoExit = true;
            }
            else if (index == 1)
            {
                // receive all messages
                ReceiveAllCanMessages();
            }
            else if (index == 2)
            {
                // exit this thread
                ReceiveStatus(UcanDotNET.USBcanServer.USBCAN_CHANNEL_CH0);
            }      
        } while ((fDoExit == false));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
 }
#endregion
```

Comment: I'm confused.  You have the GUI thread and other threads doing USB/CAN comms.  Why is the GUI thread hanging?  If it's hanging because you are trying to signal the comms thread to terminate and waiting on its handle, (Thread.Join), then just don't do it!  Signal it to finish and, well, just don't wait on it.  Do you need it to finish anyway - why not just leave it lying around?

Comment: This could be a good place to use a BackgroundWorker

Comment: In the case `index == 2` you have a comment `// exit this thread` but you're not setting `fDoExit = true`.

Answer (score 0):

> How to gracefully terminate the thread and return to the UI thread?

If the thread is blocking inside one of these UcanDotNet calls then you will have to use another UcanDotNet API to unblock it...assuming that this library has the ability to gracefully terminate one of its operations. I am not familiar with this UcanDotNet library so I do not know what its capabilities are.

If, like most 3rd libaries, this UcanDotNet library does not provide the necessary means to cancel an operation then you really have no other choice but to put all of these calls in another process and communicate with it via WCF. That way if you have to terminate it abruptly then you just kill process. Kill another process is safer than calling `Thread.Abort` anyway since aborting threads can corrupt memory.

> Why is this transmission and reception thread not aborting and hanging
>   the UI thread?

`Thread.Abort` is a blocking call. It waits for the abort to be injected into the thread. I suspect your problem is that the thread is running in a context that that does not allow asynchronous exception injections such as a `finally` block or unmanaged code. This is fairly easy to demonstrate with the following code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 0;
    var t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            while (true) i++;
        }
    });
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    t.Abort(); // this blocks indefinitely!
    Console.WriteLine("aborted"); // never gets here!
}
```